# How can I specify which CdkVirtualScrollViewport to use?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 3  lists and I need to select a particular one so I can run scrollToIndex on it.

This works, but it only targets the first CDK list.

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
```

I tried this but there is no scrollToIndex property on ElementRef

```
@ViewChild('viewportB', { read: ElementRef }) viewport: ElementRef;
```

Here is the function that I'm using that scrolls to the element

```
scrollToElement(duration: string) {
    this.captionResults$.subscribe((items) => {
      const index = items.findIndex(item => item.time === duration);
            console.log(items, duration, index)
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.viewport.scrollToIndex(index, 'smooth');
      }
    });
}
```